# Both A and B occurs

Tags: probability

Two events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A) = 0.5$, $\mathsf P(B\mid A')=0.5$ and $\mathsf P(A\mid B')=\frac{4}{9}$, find that the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occurs.

My answer:

first I find $\mathsf P(A\cup B)$ which is $P(A) +$ $\mathsf P(B\cap A')$$=0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75$

Next, I do not know how to continue. Help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Does $A'$ denote the complement of $A$?

Comment: Yes it denotes complement of A

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that
\begin{align}
P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B')(1-P(B))
\end{align}
to find $P(A|B)$ in terms of $P(B)$. Then you can write $P(B)$ in terms of $P(A \cap B)$ using $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Finally, use
\begin{align}
P(B \cap A)+P(B \cap A')=P(B)
\end{align}
to find $P(A \cap B)$

Comment: And so, following your suggestion to its conclusion, do we get a specific final value for $\Pr(A\cap B)$ or an expression that still involves unknowns?  Is this by itself enough proof to show there is not a unique answer?

Comment: You will get a unique value of $P(A\cap B)$